# Need workaround for document.getElementById in order to cycle through multiple ID possibilities. Classes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, getelementbyid

I have 30 links in my HTML document, all of which, when clicked, trigger one specific div to change it's id using a js function.

Here are three of the 30 links followed by the single div with the id that changes.

```
<a href="#" onclick="changediv_1()">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changediv_2()">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changediv_3()">Link 3</a>

<div id="contain"></div>
```

Here is the div id change function (working, but not to my liking):

```
    function changediv_1()
    {   
        if (document.getElementById("contain")) {  
            document.getElementById("contain").setAttribute("id", "contain_1");
        }

    }
```

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM**: When I click Link 1 it changes the div id from "contain" to "contain_1", no problem there. Now the div name is "contain_1", so if I try to click Link 2 after clicking link 1 it won't work, because the div id is now "contain_1" and each function can only call for 1 id.

I need the above function to check for multiple divs (ie: #contain, #contain_1, #contain_2).

**ideally** like this:

```
    function changediv_2()
    {   
        if (document.getElementById("**contain, contain_1, contain_2, ...**")) {  
            document.getElementById("**contain, contain_1, contain_2, ...**").setAttribute("id", "contain_x");
        }

    }
```

I researched and tried applying .getElementByClass and it did not work - function seemed to only work with an id. There has to be a way around me posting the function 900 (no exaggeration) times to support each situation. Thank you so much for patience and reading my freaking novel of a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this use data and use on.click instead of inline javascript function
**HTML**

```
<a href="#" data-contain="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" data-contain="2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" data-contain="3">Link 3</a>

<div id="contain" class="containDiv"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function () {
        var contain = "contain_" + $(this).data('contain');
        $('.containDiv').attr('id', contain);
        //contain == contain_(1,2,3)
        /*
         Rest of your code to read from php and put into contain?
      */
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! So you're saying I can get rid of the <a onclick="change_div1()"></a>?

Comment: Yea exactly, the on('click') is the function instead remember to wrap the code with DOM ready $(document).ready(function(){....});

Comment: @MichaelIsley btw Why do you want to change the div id?

Comment: Sorry man I'm a little confused with the DEMO (thank you for making tho).. My id's aren't declared in css at all. I just need the actual div id to be changed on the page so that when my database accesses that single page every 10 seconds, it will spit out different info if the id is changed. Does that change anything?

Comment: I need the div to actually READ "contain_x" after x link is clicked. That way, when the php accesses the page 10 seconds later, it will act accordingly to whichever ID it picks up.

Comment: The css was just to show that the ID changes @MichaelIsley if the thing you want to read is contain_1,2,3,4 when link 1,2,3,4 is clicked? If so check the new update in the answer in 2 sec

Comment: Absolutely fascinating how quickly you're doing this. Let me review it and see if I understand exactly what's going on. (new to js)

Comment: I'm testing and it doesn't seem to be working. In your browser, when you open up the inspector, the div id should be changing to "contain_1" according to clicking link 1 and so on. It should be happening live. It's not for me? Do I still need to be including my getElementById code from above?

Comment: @MichaelIsley i was thinking of not changing the id and using the string contain, but i've updated the code so it changes the div id

Comment: hmm. Lol sorry - it still doesn't seem to be running correctly on my end. Do I need to fill in the commented out section for it to run?

Comment: You need to wrap the onclick with DOM ready : `$(function(){....});` i've updated the answer @MichaelIsley

Comment: DUDE! That's it!! Thanks so much! There's no way for you to delete the code above your answer, huh?

Comment: @MichaelIsley i'm glad it works :) which code do you mean? the first onclick?

Comment: yeah exactly that. I'm not supposed to be using that, am I? LOL :D